# Python chrs not showing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i have a string that has something like `"Hi \\x00"` and when i try and use something like

```
thatstring = thatstring.replace("\\x00",chr(0))
```

and then save it to a file

```
f = open("test.txt","r+")
f.seek(0)
f.write(thatstring)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

and in the file it will come out as "Hi \NULL" (NULL is representing the chr)

I think the problem is that i am writing to the file in r+ mode instead of br+ so it will put a \ before the chr but i cant use br+ because it has to write to the file with a "byte like format" and my string would have to contain letters and "special chrs".

I am using python 3.x

How can i avoid this?

Comment: To write to a file in python, you need to use `w` (write) not `r` (read) mode. Same idea in C

Comment: Yes but r+ lets you read and write

Comment: He's using `r+` which allows writing.

Comment: @aidan gotcha. I forgot about that bit

Comment: Is your file *literally* containing a double backsslash and `x` and `0`, `0`? Because your code only replaces **one** backslash.

Comment: No, binary mode is not the issue here.

Comment: To build on @MartijnPieters comment, your replacement `\\x00` ends up becoming `\x00` because it is escaped. You could use a raw string instead: `r'\\x00'` and then your slashes will be interpreted as slashes and not escape characters

Comment: Binary mode affects newlines, so it shouldn't be the problem here.

Comment: @zachyee so if i use `thatstring = thatstring.replace("\\x00",r"\x00")` then it will work? Because in plain text it is \x00 but replaceing it with `chr(0)` should be the same.. EDIT- It does not need to be escaped it should be \x00 its just the output of my program is \\x00

Comment: @aidan: wrong way around, see my answer. The *first* argument should use a raw string literal, not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text in the file is a *literal* `\\x00`, so **two** backslashes. Your code then only replaces **one** of those backslashes:

```
>>> filecontents = r'Hi \\x00'  # raw string literal to disable escape sequences
>>> list(filecontents.partition(' ')[-1])  # only the part after the space
['\\', '\\', 'x', '0', '0']
>>> filecontents.replace("\\x00", chr(0))
'Hi \\\x00'
>>> list(_.partition(' ')[-1])  # last result, everything after the space
['\\', '\x00']
```

File contents are not subject to Python's string literal escape expansions, so there is no need to escape the escape here.

Either replace *both* backslashes or only use one backslash in your file. Replacing both is easiest done with another raw string literal:

```
thatstring = thatstring.replace(r"\\x00", chr(0))
```

Comment: Thanks the `thatstring = thatstring.replace(r"\\x00", chr(0))` solution worked fine for me and the text is displaying fine in the file thanks!